# is there reverse function for \http_parse_headers()?

Tags: php, http

PHP function `\http_parse_headers()` parses HTTP headers into an associative array.

But is there some reverse function? Which parses associative array into HTTP headers?

Cannot find anything :(

(it's for saveing email into textual `.eml` file)

Comment: No, there isn't. But it's so trivial to create one on your own, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a function that turns associative array into text-representation of headers. The reason: this function is extremely trivial to create.

Headers are defined as `key: value` delimiter is `\r\n`. 
There is another `\r\n` delimiter between headers and body.

Lets take an example array:

```
$headers = [
    'Content-Length': 50,
    'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
];
```

The goal: provide a string that represents HTTP headers

```
function parse_array_to_headers(array $headers)
{
    $result = [];
    $delimiter = "\r\n";

    foreach($headers as $name => $value)
    {
        $result[] = sprintf("%s: %s", $name, $value);
    }

    return implode($delimiter, $result);
}
```

Note: this function **will not** check the validity of array and it won't return the string with two repetitions of `\r\n` at the end. This example serves to show how easy it should be to add missing function. Adjust according to your needs. Also, I didn't test this so don't copy paste it! :)